# Why do I get this strange output with an associative array in bash when I perform a manual bubble sort?

Tags: linux, bash, associative-array, bubble-sort

I have a bash associative array that looks like this

```
declare -A arraySalary=( [1]=1000 [8]=3000 [2]=2000)
```

I am learning bash scripting and am trying to implement a bubble sort on the array 
with this piece of code

```
sortedDesc=false
while ! $sortedDesc ;
do
    sortedDesc=true
    for ((currentIndex=0; currentIndex<$((${#arraySalary[@]} -1)); currentIndex++))
    do
        if [[ ${arraySalary[$((currentIndex))]} -lt ${arraySalary[$((currentIndex + 1))]} ]]
        then
            sortedDesc=false    
            biggerNumber=${arraySalary[((currentIndex - 1))]}
            arraySalary[$((currentIndex + 1))]=${arraySalary[$((currentIndex))]}
            arraySalary[currentIndex]=${biggerNumber}
            echo "swapped"
        fi
    done
done

echo "Printing new values"
# Print new values
for key in "${!arraySalary[@]}";
do
    echo $key "->" ${arraySalary[$key]}
done
```

but the output I get is

```
swapped
swapped
Printing new values
0 -> 2000
1 -> 1000
2 ->
```

Can someone please explain why this is? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you have chosen to use an associative array instead of an ordinary array, but you need to be aware that the index of an associative array is not a numeric context.

If  `arraySalary` had been declared with `-a` instead of `-A`, then this would have been fine:

```
arraySalary[currentIndex]=${biggerNumber}
```

because the index of an ordinaey array is a numeric context, and in numeric contexts you can use variabke names without `$`. But since it is associative, what that does is set the element whose key is the string  `currentIndex`. What you want is:

```
arraySalary[$currentIndex]=${biggerNumber}
```

It is not necessary to write `$((currentIndex))`; bash does not distinguish between integers and strings which contain the integer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting an array just by its value will be easy. In the case that you sort keys
 by its value by using an assoc array, you need to introduce another array to hold the order of the elements because an assoc array is orderless.

Let's name the new array `index` which holds `(1 8 2 ..)` then the script will look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arraySalary=([1]=1000 [8]=3000 [2]=2000)
declare -a index=("${!arraySalary[@]}")

sortedDesc=false
while ! $sortedDesc ;
do
    sortedDesc=true
    for ((i=0; i<$((${#index[@]} - 1)); i++))
    do
        if [[ ${arraySalary[${index[$i]}]} -lt ${arraySalary[${index[$(($i + 1))]}]} ]]
        then
            sortedDesc=false
            biggerIndex=${index[$(($i + 1))]}
            index[$(($i + 1))]=${index[$i]}
            index[$i]=$biggerIndex
            echo "swapped"
        fi
    done
done

echo "Printing new values"
# Print new values
for key in "${index[@]}";
do
    echo $key "->" ${arraySalary[$key]}
done
```

which yields

```
swapped
swapped
swapped
Printing new values
8 -> 3000
2 -> 2000
1 -> 1000
```